# Issue with SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, connection-string, sqlplus

I have a database that I am trying to connect to through SQL Plus. I run this command from the command line:

```
sqlplus username/password@//hostname:port/sid
```

I use this connection string instead of using tsnames. The error I keep getting is

```
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

The weird thing is that using the same connection information I can connect just fine through SQL Developer. I can see the tables, users, and everything else. Anyone know what could be going on?

P.S. I tried setting up tsnames but it just gave the same thing as using the connection string.

Comment: What is the tnsnames.ora entry that you tried to add?  Exactly how are you configuring SQL Developer?  Are you entering the "sid" from the SQL*Plus connection string in the "SID" or in the "Service Name" text box in SQL Developer?  Does the listener actually support a service with the same name as the database's SID?

Comment: Are the SID and Service name the same for your database?

Comment: On the server run lsnrctl status to see what services are registered.

Comment: actually lsnrctl services is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my boss found the solution. Turns out the sid is different when connecting through SQL Plus then through SQL Developer. Seemingly in just this one case. I have no idea why this is but that was the reason. Very odd and I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you confusing SID and service_name?

Comment: I could be. I'll do a search on the difference between the two.